# efficiently pick set of products to fill a budget?

Tags: database, algorithm, search

I have a SQL table with product categories and prices..

```
product_name | category | price
product A    |  cat 1   | 10.00
product B    |  cat 3   | 20.00
product C    |  cat 2   | 5.00
product D    |  cat 1   | 15.00
```

I want to supply categories and a budget, and have an algorithm pick a set of products to fill the budget.

For example:

Find a set of products in 'cat 1' and 'cat 3' which fit within my budget of 30.00.

In the case above, the algorithm should return the set (product A, product B).

How should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: This requires only basic SQL. I suggest you find a good online tutorial.

Comment: Why isn't product D  also a valid answer?

Comment: You should also learn about the Knapsack Problem.

Comment: I edited your question so it asks what I think you are trying to ask. One important clarification is needed. Why are (D,D) and (A,D) not also solutions?

Comment: (D, D) and (A, D) because they dont have category 3 in their set. (B, D) could also be a solution since they both have category cat 1 and cat 3, that's the gist of the problem. I don't have any code yet to show but that was the problem as described

Comment: Thanks @Code-Apprentice! I'll look into the knapsack problem..

Answer (score 0):

The knapsack problem pointed me to the right direction.. Thanks @Code-Apprentice!

Answer (score -1):

```
    select product_name from tablename where price <='30';
```

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question.